# Getting C# options when I right click on vs code folder. Need to get back normal options when right click on vs code folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting this C# options when I right click on a folder in vs code.
I need to get back my normal settings (without C# options on right click).
I might have unknowingly changed some settings. And now I am gettings this always. I have already deleted the settings.json completely but stil getting it.
I am using ubuntu.
Image below:
[image]

Comment: Which extensions do you've installed?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Just searched C# in extensions and removed them all. It's not showing c# options now.